# Substitute or merge output of two commands in one, using one line command

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, output, command-substitution

How can I merge the output of two commands in one, using one command?

command1 output:

```
ID      NAME1  COLUMN2
xxx-1   aaa    bbb     
xxx-2   ccc    ddd     
xxx-3   eee    fff     
xxx-4   nnn    mmm
```

command2 output:

```
COLUMN3   COLUMN4   ID
kkk       www       xxx-3
kkk       ppp       xxx-1
kkk       qqq       xxx-4
lll       ttt       xxx-2
kkk       rrr       xxx-2
```

NOTE: `command1 xxx-2` returns `ccc` (NAME1 field)

Expected one command and substitution happening on the screen, no files involved.

Expected result:

```
COLUMN3   COLUMN4   NAME1
kkk       www       eee
kkk       ppp       aaa
kkk       qqq       nnn
lll       ttt       ccc
kkk       rrr       ccc
```

Many Thanks.

**

**
EDITED: Added 2 dumb scripts with the results of each command for testing.

command1.sh >

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
  echo 'ID                                     NAME1                  COLUMN2
3cc45fe6-gqee-321f-c143-w3d1d278912c   aaa                    bbb bab bab
4a39466b-211d-48e2-a86b-db022c10fe59   ccc                    ddd ddd daa ddd
adw45fe6-fqxe-261g-k172-a7d1x277112d   eee                    fff fff
f28894d0-cf40-4cff-a19a-a6893f88dd67   nnn                    mmm mamm mmm'
elif [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
    if [[ "$1" == "3cc45fe6-gqee-321f-c143-w3d1d278912c" ]]; then
        echo "aaa"
    elif [[ "$1" == "4a39466b-211d-48e2-a86b-db022c10fe59" ]]; then
        echo "ccc"
    elif [[ "$1" == "adw45fe6-fqxe-261g-k172-a7d1x277112d" ]]; then
        echo "eee"
    elif [[ "$1" == "f28894d0-cf40-4cff-a19a-a6893f88dd67" ]]; then
        echo "nnn"
    else
        echo "Error from server (NotFound)"
    fi
fi
```

command2.sh >

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

echo 'COLUMN3    COLUMN4                                 ID
kkk        www wwaaw www www                       adw45fe6-fqxe-261g-k172-a7d1x277112d
kkk        pppppppppppp paaapp ppp ppp             3cc45fe6-gqee-321f-c143-w3d1d278912c
kkk        qqq qqq qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq                 f28894d0-cf40-4cff-a19a-a6893f88dd67
lll        tttttttttttt ttttttttt ttt ttt          4a39466b-211d-48e2-a86b-db022c10fe59
kkk        rrrrrr rrrrrr rrrraarrrrr rrr           4a39466b-211d-48e2-a86b-db022c10fe59'
```

Comment: How strictly should be adhere to the "no files involved" restriction? A process substitution, for example, may use a temporary file behind the scenes... And why does it need to be a one-liner? By the way, even a multi-line script can be rewritten in a single line. It would be unreadable and unmaintainable (like most "one-liners"), but it would be on a single line.

Comment: @Kusalananda do you know of any process substitution implementation which is using temporary files? (and by that I don't mean named pipes/FIFOs created in /tmp) This is not a rhetorical question.

Comment: @mosvy I just checked the `bash` sources. `bash` will use `/dev/fd/...` if that hierarchy exists. If it doesn't it creates a temporary named pipe. So not a temporary _regular_ file. `zsh` uses `pipe()`, so no files created. My bad, at least on that account.

Comment: I now about about bash, I was just afraid that some other shell which doesn't support process substitution yet took a shortcut towards it;-) Using temporary files would grossly break the semantics, a command like `foo <(bar) <(baz)` is supposed to process the output of  `bar` and `baz` without waiting for them to terminate.

Comment: Are those columns separated by tabs? And are the header lines included in the command outputs?

Comment: Yes, columns separated by tabs, and headers included on the output. Seams that the `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {$3=a[$3]} 1' <(command1) <(command2)` get messy when there's space in a field.

Comment: Below my answer you said `the columns are fixed spaced` - which is it, tab-separated fields or fixed-width fields or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton I've made some tests, and it's not really fixed or tabbed. The "ID" is the only one fixed because is a GUID. The other columns follow the header (COLUMN3.   COLUMN4...) and actually variable based on the larger field.  Sorry that I didn't included that variable to the problem before.

Comment: What you show in your update looks like fixed width fields to me with the output of your second command producing a first field that's 11 chars wide (a "field" in this terminology includes the non-spaces and the spaces that follow it before the next set of non-spaces), the second one about 41 chars, and the 3rd/final field going to the end of the line. Is that not correct?

Comment: @EdMorton That's correct. It's "fixed", based on the header spacing. The results expected is the same output of the command2, but replacing the field ID with the correlating NAME1 field from the command1.

Comment: @EdMorton the updated one liner command is awesome and works as expected. Many Thanks. You are an "awk master".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {$3=a[$3]} 1' <(command1) <(command2)
```

might be what you're looking for.

I tweaked the above and re-ran given the output the 2 command scripts you added produces:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { map[$1]=$2; next }
    { key=$NF; sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*$/,""); print $0 map[key] }
' <(./command1.sh) <(./command2.sh)
COLUMN3    COLUMN4                                 NAME1
kkk        www wwaaw www www                       eee
kkk        pppppppppppp paaapp ppp ppp             aaa
kkk        qqq qqq qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq                 nnn
lll        tttttttttttt ttttttttt ttt ttt          ccc
kkk        rrrrrr rrrrrr rrrraarrrrr rrr           ccc
```

I wrote it such that the mapping will work and the output will retain the same spacing as the input whether the 3rd field of the first input stream or the 2nd field of the 2nd input stream has spaces or not or if the spaces are blanks or tabs or whether the fields are fixed-width or not. The only fields that cannot have spaces are fields 1 and 2 of input 1 and field 3 of input 2.

Comment: This command alone does not work, because the fields can have spaces and the columns are fixed spaced.

Comment: Then that's what you should have shown in your sample input/output.

Comment: Agree. Sorry.  The original example was not clear. At least the column results follow the spacing of the header (first line).

Comment: Tested with multiple commands and working like a chart. Thanks again @EdMorton